# shell - extract multiple fields from plist via PlistBuddy

Tags: shell, plist

I need to extract some values from a plist file. I've found the tool called PlistBuddy on OSX, which is what I use for the task (I use shell script, eventually I will try with python, but for the time being I will stick with shell).

The problem is that I need to get values, which has the same name ("time" and "revolutions"), but they are located in different branches of the plist file.
This is how the plist is organized:

```
root
    iteration1
        compound 1
            time
            revolutions
        compound 2
            time
            revolutions
        compound 3
            time
            revolutions
    iteration2
        compound 1
            time
            revolutions
        compound 2
            time
            revolutions
        compound 3
            time
            revolutions
```

At this point, I am trying to get the time and revolutions values, and calculate an average at least, for each compound, based on the number of iteration.

My first approach was to have a for cycle, for the n iteration, and then a list of all the compounds, with the values of time and revolutions, all saved in an array in sequence.

This is really prone to error, since I had no ID for each couple of values, and it would rely on the fact that the position is always the same...as you can imagine it is really bad as algorithm.

Another approach that I tried, is to read each couple of values, for all the iteration, calculate the average and then move on to the next compound, until I am done; but this approach seems quite involuted.

Now, a good solution would be a dictionary, so I can save each couple of values under each compound, but shell does not have dictionary; so I am a bit lost about how could I tackle the issue.

Ideally I should get each couple of value for each compound, and then calculate the average for n iteration.

I am still exploring solutions, so if anyone have a suggestion about how to tackle the issue, I would really appreciate. Also the PlistBuddy tool seems quite strict with its syntax.

I am tempted to use python and just put aside shell script, but that would take me more time, since I know little of python, in relation to plist handling.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `bash4` has associative arrays (= dictionary). But I think your task is complex enough to use python instead. Don't "program" in the shell, use proper programming languages for that.

Comment: You definitely want to use Python straightaway. You cannot do this in Shell without wasting a lot of time. In python (or Perl) you should be able to do this in 20 lines of code. If you need help let me know (I use Perl for this though).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; so far I wrote a routine that is horrible in bash; it works but it is hard to maintain. I ended up writing a function, passing basically the name of the compound that I wish to gather data from, and a second function that process the data...it hurts my eyes. I will give a try to python and see if I can come up with something decent. Thanks!